# How to send a facebook notification to a user without using the SDK with only PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents, content-type

I don't know if this is possible, i'm having a problem getting the PHP SDK to work and i don't want to send App Access Token to browser.

**So i tried the following.**

```
$contextData = array ( 
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
               /* 'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query*/ );
$context = stream_context_create (array('https' =>$contextData));
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/userAppId/notifications?access_token=********&href=index.php&template=test';
$result =  file_get_contents ($url,false,$context);
echo $result;
```

**Problem**: I get this error.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/userAppId/notifications?
access_token=********&amp;href=index.php&amp;template=test): 
failed to open stream:HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in
C:\wamp\app\fb\fb_notificationsphp.php on line 19
```

Comment: I think you use `curl()` for request to Facebook

Comment: @kushalsuthar Can u give more info based on the example on the question please